# NEST 1.0.0 beta no longer maps my nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

After upgrading NEST to 1.0.0 beta and my Elasticsearch server to 1.1.1, NEST no longer maps my nested object. My mapping looks like this:

```
userdocuments: {
  properties: {
    id: {
      index: not_analyzed
      type: string
    }
    logs: {
      include_in_all: true
      include_in_root: true
      include_in_parent: true
      properties: {
        logId: {
          include_in_all: true
          index: not_analyzed
          type: string
        }
        name: {
          include_in_all: true
          index: not_analyzed
          type: string
        }
      }
      type: nested
    }
  }
}
```

My c# models looks like this:

```
public class UserDocument
{
    public UserDocument()
    {
        Logs = new List<LogRefDocument>();
    }

    public List<LogRefDocument> Logs { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class LogRefDocument
{
    public string LogId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When doing a Get<UserDocument>(id).Source, the user document is returned, but the list of LogRefDocument objects are not mapped to the Logs list.

Any help?

Comment: NEST 1.0 also has `.Source(id)` that maps to the `_source` operation in elasticsearch. Can you post what either Get / Source return (i.e result.ConnectionStatus.ToString()) You might need to set `ExposeRawResponse()` on your `ConnectionSettings` to hold a copy of the string response result (will be enabled in debug by default in the next version).

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you on this one, Martijn. I had to put my cluster upgrade on hold, but will look at it within the next week or two. The funny thing where, that it worked fine localhost. I will test again with 1.2.1 and dig into any problems. Thanks.

Comment: @MartijnLaarman Dough! Found out that I needed to call PluralizeTypeNames on ConnectionSettings in order to get it working with the old index.